# Como usar range de letras do alfabeto em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

estou tentando fazer um programa que faça as letras do alfabeto em triangulo tipo assim, o usuário entra com um numero inteiro e o resultado é exibido em forma de triangulo.

```
7:
A

BB

CCC

DDDD

EEEEE

FFFFFF

GGGGGGG

4:
A

BB

CCC

DDDD
```

Já tentei usar o laço `for` mas não consegui. Segue minha tentativa:

```
N = int(input())

if N == 1:
    print('A')
if N == 2:
    print('A\n'
          'BB')
if N == 3:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC')
if N == 4:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD')
if N == 5:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE')
if N == 6:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF')
if N == 7:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG')
if N == 8:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH')
if N == 9:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n')
if N == 10:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ')
if N == 11:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ\n'
          'KKKKKKKKKKK\n')
if N == 12:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ\n'
          'KKKKKKKKKKK\n'
          'LLLLLLLLLLLL\n')
if N == 13:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ\n'
          'KKKKKKKKKKK\n'
          'LLLLLLLLLLLL\n'
          'MMMMMMMMMMMMM\n')
if N == 14:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ\n'
          'KKKKKKKKKKK\n'
          'LLLLLLLLLLLL\n'
          'MMMMMMMMMMMMM\n'
          'NNNNNNNNNNNNNN')
if N == 15:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ\n'
          'KKKKKKKKKKK\n'
          'LLLLLLLLLLLL\n'
          'MMMMMMMMMMMMM\n'
          'NNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n'
          'OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\n')
if N == 16:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ\n'
          'KKKKKKKKKKK\n'
          'LLLLLLLLLLLL\n'
          'MMMMMMMMMMMMM\n'
          'NNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n'
          'OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\n'
          'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP\n')
if N == 17:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ\n'
          'KKKKKKKKKKK\n'
          'LLLLLLLLLLLL\n'
          'MMMMMMMMMMMMM\n'
          'NNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n'
          'OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\n'
          'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP\n'
          'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ\n')
if N == 18:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ\n'
          'KKKKKKKKKKK\n'
          'LLLLLLLLLLLL\n'
          'MMMMMMMMMMMMM\n'
          'NNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n'
          'OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\n'
          'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP\n'
          'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ\n'
          'RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR\n')
if N == 19:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ\n'
          'KKKKKKKKKKK\n'
          'LLLLLLLLLLLL\n'
          'MMMMMMMMMMMMM\n'
          'NNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n'
          'OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\n'
          'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP\n'
          'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ\n'
          'RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR\n'
          'SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS\n')
if N == 20:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ\n'
          'KKKKKKKKKKK\n'
          'LLLLLLLLLLLL\n'
          'MMMMMMMMMMMMM\n'
          'NNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n'
          'OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\n'
          'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP\n'
          'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ\n'
          'RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR\n'
          'SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS\n'
          'TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT\n')
if N == 21:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ\n'
          'KKKKKKKKKKK\n'
          'LLLLLLLLLLLL\n'
          'MMMMMMMMMMMMM\n'
          'NNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n'
          'OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\n'
          'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP\n'
          'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ\n'
          'RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR\n'
          'SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS\n'
          'TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT\n'
          'UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU\n')
if N == 22:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ\n'
          'KKKKKKKKKKK\n'
          'LLLLLLLLLLLL\n'
          'MMMMMMMMMMMMM\n'
          'NNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n'
          'OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\n'
          'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP\n'
          'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ\n'
          'RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR\n'
          'SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS\n'
          'TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT\n'
          'UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU\n'
          'VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV\n')
if N == 23:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ\n'
          'KKKKKKKKKKK\n'
          'LLLLLLLLLLLL\n'
          'MMMMMMMMMMMMM\n'
          'NNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n'
          'OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\n'
          'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP\n'
          'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ\n'
          'RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR\n'
          'SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS\n'
          'TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT\n'
          'UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU\n'
          'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n')
if N == 24:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ\n'
          'KKKKKKKKKKK\n'
          'LLLLLLLLLLLL\n'
          'MMMMMMMMMMMMM\n'
          'NNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n'
          'OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\n'
          'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP\n'
          'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ\n'
          'RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR\n'
          'SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS\n'
          'TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT\n'
          'UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU\n'
          'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n'
          'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW\n')
if N == 25:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ\n'
          'KKKKKKKKKKK\n'
          'LLLLLLLLLLLL\n'
          'MMMMMMMMMMMMM\n'
          'NNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n'
          'OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\n'
          'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP\n'
          'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ\n'
          'RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR\n'
          'SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS\n'
          'TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT\n'
          'UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU\n'
          'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n'
          'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW\n'
          'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY\n')
if N == 26:
    print('A\n'
          'BB\n'
          'CCC\n'
          'DDDD\n'
          'EEEEE\n'
          'FFFFFF\n'
          'GGGGGGG\n'
          'HHHHHHHH\n'
          'IIIIIIIII\n'
          'JJJJJJJJJJ\n'
          'KKKKKKKKKKK\n'
          'LLLLLLLLLLLL\n'
          'MMMMMMMMMMMMM\n'
          'NNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n'
          'OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\n'
          'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP\n'
          'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ\n'
          'RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR\n'
          'SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS\n'
          'TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT\n'
          'UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU\n'
          'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n'
          'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW\n'
          'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY\n'
          'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ\n')
```

Como obtenho esse mesmo resultado usando laço `for`?

Comment: Poderia nos mostrar como fez com o laço `for`?

Comment: Lucas, eu editei a sua pergunta numa tentativa de deixa-la mais clara. Caso não aprove as modificações você pode entrar no [histórico de edições](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/510974/revisions) e reverter as modificações.

Comment: https://ideone.com/AkNqFj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O módulo [string](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/string.html) da biblioteca padrão python define algumas constantes entre as quais [`string.ascii_uppercase`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase) é a sequencia das letras maiúsculas `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`.

É possível [enumerar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) e iterar por uma [fatia](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/glossary.html#term-slice), do tamanho escolhido pelo usuário, da sequencia de letras e a cada elemento iterado o imprimir repetidamente com o auxilio do [operador * de repetição sequencias](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

```
import string

N = int(input("Digite a altura da pirâmide:"))
#Itera pela fatia de caracteres onde i é índice e c é o caractere com o índice começando em 1... 
for i,c in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase[:N], 1):
  print(c*i);         #...imprime o caractere o repetindo i vezes.
```

<sup>Teste o código no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/QJn0ml)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Pra isso você pode usar as funções globais do Python como a `chr`.

```py
# Quantidade de linhas
value = int(input("Digite: "))

# Executa a quantidade de vezes digitada
# inicialmente, para cada nova iteração
# ele printa uma nova letra
for i in range(value):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        # Mostra o caracter n vezes
        print(chr(65 + i), end="") # 65 = 'A' na tabela ASCII
    print("")
```